# JQuery Conflict / Not working 1.5.2

Tags: jquery

I currently have this JQuery code that works perfectly with 1.5.2 but will not work on the latest Jquery library:

```
$(function() {

var $el, leftPos, newWidth,
    $mainNav = $("#example-one");

$mainNav.append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");
var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");

$magicLine
    .width($(".current_page_item").width())
    .css("left", $(".current_page_item a").position().left)
    .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
    .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());

$("#example-one li a").hover(function() {
    $el = $(this);
    leftPos = $el.position().left;
    newWidth = $el.parent().width();
    $magicLine.stop().animate({
        left: leftPos,
        width: newWidth
    });
}, function() {
    $magicLine.stop().animate({
        left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
        width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
    });    
});
});
```

Please could you let me know why this is not working and what i need to implement to make it work with the latest - 1.11.0?

Please see the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/danieljoseph/U8aRp/

The orange line will disappear when you run it on JQuery 1.8.3 +.

Thanks

Comment: Any console errors? Also, have you tried using [jQuery-Migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) to see if anything pops up?

Comment: Hi Brad. I have just downloaded firebug and it's not showing any errors. Also tried jQuery-Migrate but thats not working either. i'm new to JQuery so i could be doing something blatantly wrong!

Comment: Please see the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/danieljoseph/U8aRp/

Comment: Well, managed to get it fixed... the problem was in this line which doesn't work from 1.7.2: newWidth = $el.parent().width();

Also, not really sure why this question was marked down!

Comment: Hi @DanielJoseph how did you get this fixed? I'm having the exact same problem....